# Does not work events magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Events do not work when I go to the product page.

> events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="adding_to_cart_before">
        <observer name="attributesProduct" instance="Ronis\SameDayDelivery\Observer\DayDelivery" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> DayDelivery.php

```
<?php

namespace Ronis\SameDayDelivery\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class DayDelivery implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    protected $_cart;

    /**
     * [__construct description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context [description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory [description]
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/daydelivery.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $productInfo = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
        $logger->info('-------------------------');
        foreach ($productInfo as $item){
            $item->getProductId();
            $logger->info($item->getProductId());
            if($item->getProductId() == '1')
            {
                echo "Item available in cart";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Item not available in cart";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got any error? or any log in the log file?

Comment: No, and does not write anything to my log

Comment: What's that event?? when you want that event to be triggered?

Comment: When I go to the product page

Comment: You mean each time when you go for product page

Comment: It should pull the data from the basket if there is a product and return a certain attribute of the product, and if there is no product in the basket, then there’s nothing to do

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

You should use this event **controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view** instead of **adding_to_cart_before**

but the problem is, it will trigger only on first time when you visit the product page, since it is cacheable page. You may try disable cacheable="false" to any of the block from product page and check then it will trigger all the time you visit.

> NOTE : It's not recommended to disable cache on product page, so try using **plugin** to do that.

Hope this information helps.

Comment: and how can I now transfer these id's to the js template so that, depending on this ids, I showed a popup on the product page